# C# Get an array to convert to a PSObject

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to use the System.Management.Automation namespace to use the built-in gridviewer from PowerShell in c#, however I can't seem to be able to get it to display my list of items, it always just returns it as one line as if I was trying to get the info of the array instead of it's members.

```
SomeClass[] list; //let's say I have a simple array of one object type
PowerShell posh = PowerShell.Create();
posh.AddCommand("Out-Gridview");
posh.AddArgument(list); //this inputs the list as first argument for the command
posh.Invoke(); //this now just opens a gridview with information about the list itself (length, syncroot, ...)
```

So what I would like is a way to translate my already existing list into a powershell-compatible object inside my C# code, preferably using only the automation library and other default .NET classes.

Comment: `posh.AddCommand("Write-Output").AddArgument(list).AddCommand("Out-GridView")` <-- pipeline will wrap your objects in `PSObject` and `Out-Gridview` should render them correctly

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed, why would I need to send it through the pipeline instead of as a parameter though?

Comment: PowerShell's object model is built on the idea that every object is wrapped in a thin `PSObject` wrapper at certain inflection points - the exchange of data across pipelines is such an inflection point :)